# Building my first CKEditor plugin using Twitter Bootstrap Icons

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, ckeditor

following this [tutorial](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials/Timestamp_Plugin) I'm trying to create my first plugin for CKEditor, the main idea here is to allow users to pick from a SELECT element any (just one at time) of the icons as in [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons) What I need to build and don't know how is a SELECT element that contains every class of those elements "icon-circle-arrow-up", "icon-globe" and so on so users can pick and write the code wherever they want and if it's possible render the element on the CKEditor area, of course Twitter Bootstrap class should be include as CSS links. What I have done so far is just this piece of code:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('twitter-icons', {
    init: function(editor) {
        editor.insertHtml();
    }
});
```

Where `insertHtml()` will write to editor something like `<i class="some_class">&nbsp;</i>` and where `some_class` should take the value picked by users in the SELECT element. Any help or ideas in how to continue from here?

**Update 1**
After research I got this:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add("tbootstrap", {
    requires: ["richcombo"],
    init: function(editor) {
        var config = editor.config, lang = editor.lang.format;

        var tb_icons = []; //new Array();
        tb_icons[0] = ["<i class='icon-glass'>&#8203;</i>", "icon-glass", "icon-glass"];
        tb_icons[1] = ["<i class='icon-music'>&#8203;</i>", "icon-music", "icon-music"];
        tb_icons[2] = ["<i class='icon-search'>&#8203;</i>", "icon-search", "icon-search"];
        tb_icons[3] = ["<i class='icon-envelope'>&#8203;</i>", "icon-envelope", "icon-envelope"];
        tb_icons[4] = ["<i class='icon-heart'>&#8203;</i>", "icon-heart", "icon-heart"];
        tb_icons[5] = ["<i class='icon-star'>&#8203;</i>", "icon-star", "icon-star"];
        tb_icons[6] = ["<i class='icon-star-empty'>&#8203;</i>", "icon-star-empty", "icon-star-empty"];
        tb_icons[7] = ["<i class='icon-user'>&#8203;</i>", "icon-user", "icon-user"];
        tb_icons[8] = ["<i class='icon-film'>&#8203;</i>", "icon-film", "icon-film"];
        tb_icons[9] = ["<i class='icon-th-large'>&#8203;</i>", "icon-th-large", "icon-th-large"];
        tb_icons[10] = ["<i class='icon-th'>&#8203;</i>", "icon-th", "icon-th"];

        editor.ui.addRichCombo("tbootstrap", {
            label: "TB Icons",
            title: "TB Icons",
            voiceLabel: "TB Icons",
            className: "cke_format",
            multiselect: false,
            panel: {
                css: [config.contentsCss, CKEDITOR.getUrl(CKEDITOR.skin.getPath("editor") + "editor.css")],
                voiceLabel: lang.panelVoiceLabel
            },
            init: function() {
                this.startGroup("tbootstrap");
                for (var this_tag in tb_icons) {
                    this.add(tb_icons[this_tag][0], tb_icons[this_tag][1], tb_icons[this_tag][2]);
                }
            },
            onClick: function(value) {
                editor.focus();
                editor.fire("saveSnapshot");
                editor.insertHtml(value);
                editor.fire("saveSnapshot");
            }
        });

        editor.insertHtml();
    }
});
```

But I'm getting this error while trying to insert the element in the editor:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>   CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(156,'​'); return
>   false;
>
> SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical void('​')

Any ideas?

**Edit 2**
Tried this:

```
tb_icons[0] = ['<i class=%27icon-glass%27>&#8203;</i>', "icon-glass", "icon-glass"];
tb_icons[1] = ['<i class=%27icon-music%27>&#8203;</i>', "icon-music", "icon-music"];
```

And this too:

```
tb_icons[0] = ["<i class=%27icon-glass%27>&#8203;</i>", "icon-glass", "icon-glass"];
tb_icons[1] = ["<i class=%27icon-music%27>&#8203;</i>", "icon-music", "icon-music"];
```

Then in `onClick()` function change this:

```
editor.insertHtml(unscape(value));
```

And the results are the same meaning same error

Comment: Why don't you use a dialog like the [smiley plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/smiley), which does pretty much the same thing?

Comment: @oleq could be an option but a doubt comes to me, how do I handle the presentation of this items? I mean I tough TB handle this on DOM ready so I'm a bit lost here

Comment: Try replacing ' with %27 so you get %27icon-glass%27 etc then replace editor.insertHtml(value); with editor.insertHtml(unescape(value));

Comment: @misterbassman see my latest edit, I tried without success

Comment: @Reynier TB doesn't use any DOM ready event, the icons are pure CSS. TB uses a font where the characters are these icons.